Compose Widget Text does not accept scaledSp
I don't want to scale the widget text size when the user changes the text size from the device settings. So, I used the below code from this post
@Composable
fun Int.scaledSp(): TextUnit {
    val value: Int = this
    return with(LocalDensity.current) {
        val fontScale = this.fontScale
        val textSize = value / fontScale
        textSize.sp
    }
}

When I use the above code in a widget, the widget crashes throwing me the below error. Is there any way I can lock the text size of the widget so the crash does not happen. I also tried replacing sp with em and it's still the same error as below.
 java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: CompositionLocal LocalDensity not present
                                                                                                        at androidx.work.impl.utils.futures.AbstractFuture.getDoneValue(AbstractFuture.java:515)
                                                                                                        at androidx.work.impl.utils.futures.AbstractFuture.get(AbstractFuture.java:474)
                                                                                                        at androidx.work.impl.WorkerWrapper$2.run(WorkerWrapper.java:316)
                                                                                                        at androidx.work.impl.utils.SerialExecutorImpl$Task.run(SerialExecutorImpl.java:96)
                                                                                                        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
                                                                                                        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:644)
                                                                                                        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1012)
                                                                                                    Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: CompositionLocal LocalDensity not present
                                                                                                        at androidx.compose.ui.platform.CompositionLocalsKt.noLocalProvidedFor(CompositionLocals.kt:211)
                                                                                                        at androidx.compose.ui.platform.CompositionLocalsKt.access$noLocalProvidedFor(CompositionLocals.kt:1)
                                                                                                        at androidx.compose.ui.platform.CompositionLocalsKt$LocalDensity$1.invoke(CompositionLocals.kt:83)
                                                                                                        at androidx.compose.ui.platform.CompositionLocalsKt$LocalDensity$1.invoke(CompositionLocals.kt:82)
                                                                                                        at kotlin.SynchronizedLazyImpl.getValue(LazyJVM.kt:74)
                                                                                                        at androidx.compose.runtime.LazyValueHolder.getCurrent(ValueHolders.kt:29)
                                                                                                        at androidx.compose.runtime.LazyValueHolder.getValue(ValueHolders.kt:31)
                                                                                                        at androidx.compose.runtime.CompositionLocalMapKt.read(CompositionLocalMap.kt:90)
                                                                                                        at androidx.compose.runtime.ComposerImpl.consume(


You should have access to the androidx.glance.LocalContext. You could get the fontScale through its Resources' Configuration; e.g., LocalContext.current.resources.configuration.fontScale.

There is no LocalDensity in Glance, btw. I probably should've mentioned the reason for the need of a workaround. Glance only has about four built-in locals, for some reason.

It fixes the crash but I'm but whenever I change the fontSize in settings the widget fontSize also changes. not sure what's the reason. @MikeM.

Yeah, you're right. That kinda makes sense, though, because it's not recomposing upon the configuration change, and the TextView's simply have the scale applied to whatever text size they ended up with after the scaleSp() calculations. I can think of two further workarounds offhand: draw the text to a Bitmap and set that on an Image instead, or have a constantly-running Service to monitor config changes and notify the Widget. Or, ya know, just let the user change their own text size. :-)

To clarify, in case you weren't yet aware, Compose isn't actually running in the Widget, 'cause you can't use custom Views in Widgets since they run inside somebody else's app. Glance is just translating the Compose code into RemoteViews, so a Text() call becomes plain old TextView. Additionally, Widgets don't get notified of configuration changes; the hosting app does, and it handles the necessary work internally. That's what's happening here: your Widget ends up with TextViews that get the scaling applied to whatever text size Glance told it at the last composition.
